# Can Label get focus while tabbing when its corrsponding control is hidden in HTML Form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accessibility

There is a small problem I am facing. I have a form, for sake of styling the checkbox has been hidden. The actual checkbox is being accessed through its label. Now the problem which arises is on tabbing in the form the checkbox is not getting the focus. Rather the focus is shifted to next control. I tried associating onfocus events for Label. Since the checkbox display is hidden the label corresponding to it is not getting focused.

Comment: So what is the actual problem? If the checkbox is hidden you won't be able to give it focus and you can't tab to a label. You might need to re-think your form design.

Comment: Could you please share some code which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set the HTML property `tabindex` to a different number (such as 99) to prevent the user from focusing on an invisible element.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.11.1

Comment: var settings = {
            'attributeName': someID 
} 
var control = $("<input type='checkbox' class='checkboxControl'/>");
$(control).attr('id', settings.attributeName); 
fieldLabel = $("<label></label>").addClass('checkbox-control').attr('for', settings.attributeName);

Comment: No this soultion didnt work for me. As of now the solution I tried was the above code. The purpose I am working this way is the style of the checkbox is helping my design. Can anyone give a work around for this problem where the checkbox can be given different style than Default HTML style

Comment: `appearance: none`. Don't forget vendor prefixes.